# View both table and chart on Tableau on 1 screen

Tags: view, tableau-api

IS there a way to view both table of data and it's chart in one place, i.e on one screen (instead of switching view via "show me" or using dashboard interactively) on Tableau?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution WITHOUT using dashboard? (ie: 2 worksheet, data table and chart, in one dashboard)

Comment: Yes exactly -without dashboard

Comment: I don't think it is possible... the best you can have is a dual axis visualization